# Reverse whole string in python using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
y = "python is cool"
def reverse(y):
    for i in range (1,1+len(y)):
        print(y[-i],end='')

print(reverse(y))
```

output - ***looc si nohtyp***
but i want this type of output - ***nohtyp si  looc***

Comment: Consider exploding the string (split it by the spaces) and reversing each word, then concat it again

Comment: This is not "Reverse the whole string" as your question title says and that might be the reason you didn't find the solution. It's "Reverse words in a string".

Answer (score 2):

You can split by space and reverse each word and concat them back:

```
y = "python is cool"
for i in y.split():
    print(''.join(list(reversed(i))),end=' ')
#nohtyp si looc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `split` the `words` then reverse each `word` and then `join` them like,

```
>>> y = "python is cool"
>>> ' '.join(x[::-1] for x in y.split())
'nohtyp si looc'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go fool `loop` mode:

```
y = "python is cool"
def reverse(y):
    new_s,temp_s = '', ''
    for i in range (0,len(y)):
        if y[i] == ' ' and temp_s:
                for j in range(1,len(temp_s)+1):
                    new_s += temp_s[-j]
                new_s += ' '
                temp_s = ''
        else:
            temp_s += y[i]
    for j in range(1,len(temp_s)+1):
        new_s += temp_s[-j]
    return new_s

print(reverse(y))
```

Output:

```
nohtyp si looc
```